# My android studio showing an error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

Recently, I have updated my SDK version to 27 from 26. and now I get red lines of error on newly created project whereas my new created Android project is running successfully. I have tried all clean project rebuild project and all possible options but red lines are not going I have attached screenshots. 
[image: MainActivity Class code]

[image]

Comment: these red lines must be showing some warning and errors ?

Comment: no, they are not showing any warnings and errors. when I run my new created project in the emulator is running successfully

Comment: jus set the cursor on those line they will show warning

Answer (score 1):

Change your targetSdkVersion and compiledSdkVersion to 27 and also change your appcompat -v7 26.1.0 to 27.?.?

Comment: there is no issue with the gradle version compatibility. this is about SDK and imports. anyhow I apply this but now it showing only Buddle with the red line